# Debug Android Permissions

Tags: permissions, debug

I would like to analyze deeply the behavior of the android permissions.
When a permission is granted or not, what android do, etc.

I have some ideas, but I would like to know which one could be the easiest one, or any new idea, or if some similar works have already been done.

So I thought about:

- frida
- android studio using the debugging
- making in local a java script using the same logic than in the aosp

The logcat in Android Studio is very powerful, I can see the ActivityTaskManager and GrantPermissionsActivity for example.
But I don't know what happened to call them, why these parameters etc.

So, if you have any ideas, any tips, any documentations, I'm interested in.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked out Stackoverflow.com? There are dozen of questions and answer about what to do to request a run-time permission. Usually one of the Google support/Androidx libraries are used which then should contain the call to request the run-time permission.

Comment: Or otherwise, browse [the Android source code directly](https://cs.android.com/search?q=permission).

Comment: @AndrewT. yes it would be the last option.
My goal is to find something to look at what's happening, as gdb can do for a binary file.

Comment: Use a framework mod like Xposed to hook into system APIs and get callbacks when they are called. In practice there is nothing very complicated happening underneath. Android framework grants (or deny) the requested permission and saves the new state in a file. The state is also cached in services like `PermissionManager`, `PackageManager` and `ActivityManager`. So that when the app wants to perform a privileged operation, it's allowed or rejected accordingly. Some permissions operate at kernel level. So the app is added (or removed) to some DAC groups (GIDs) when permission state changes.

Comment: Ok thank you @IrfanLatif.
I read a lot of documentation to understand how the permissions are managed. And you are totally right. But I did this post because I would like to trace the services you mentioned, to see what's going on, what is called etc, in order that I don't need to read and understand this part in the aosp.
The problem is that I will have to, I think.